# getting users back in app through homescreen integration

Tags: android, android-widget, android-notifications, android-livefolders

I'm trying to figure out ways to get users to return into my app more often

so far i have: http://android.arnodenhond.com/tutorials/home-screen

1. Widgets
2. Live Folders
3. Shortcuts

- Install shortcut

4. Quick Search Box
5. Notifications

please answer any other tricks you know of?

Comment: Does adding all this functionality actually improve your app or make it easier for the user to use? If you are simply trying to make a user return to your app, you should focus on designing an app that people will want to use instead of trying to "trick" people into coming back to it.

Comment: well (apart from notifications) its up to the user to add the stuff to the homescreen. obviously it only makes sense to provide the features if there is any value for him. by "tricks" i didn't mean "tricking"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a broadcast receiver for example when ever user turns on the Wi-Fi or Bluetooth. You could as show a notification to the user to fire your application

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have it pretty much down functionality wise so

- Widgets - you say you have widgets, but how good are they? In my experience widgets are one of the most-used Home-screen features. Do you offer per-widget configuration? Do they look nice and fit well with the other widgets?
- User Interface - it's always important to have a sharp looking app; if the functionality is there, then this should be the big focus. Try something a little different, make use of some animations (sparingly)

Some other things you might want to look at, not specifically to do with the Homescreen but they apply to it too:

- Responsiveness - nothing puts off a user like a slow or crashing app
- Icon - the number of Android developers I have come across that put out an app with either (a) an extremely large icon (b) a tiny icon or (c) an icon that fails to even attempt to comply with the icon design guidelines; the icon is often the first thing a user will see after installing your app so it's important to get it right, there are [icon design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) for a reason.

Also please don't pop up random notifications (I'm not saying you are, just don't!), notifications should happen for a reason or most likely they will just end annoying the end user who will uninstall your app.

I generally find that

1. Live folders do not seem to be that popular
2. Although the search box gets used for in-app searches, very, very few people make use of the Global search functionality from the Homescreen since most people never enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I think notifications are your best bet. As long as they provide value of course.

Answer (score -1):

I think you already have all ways that available on Android app. level.

---

If you want more features above a normal Launcher to get users return to your app., this idea following is quite nice I think. 
Check out [**this**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRxVYXkO0Hs).
As you can see, the app show up on any activity such as a Map.

Comment: any suggestions on other levels perhaps?